# How to use data in rChart Highcharts

Tags: r, highcharts, rcharts

I have the following table with name "taula":

```
Freq levelArea levelSeveridad
1         1              1
2         2              1
3         3              1
2         4              1
3         8              1
2         9              1
```

I want to do a bubble plot with rChart Highcharts, I am using the following code:

```
 a <- rCharts::Highcharts$new()
  a$chart(type = 'bubble' , plotBorderWidth=0, zoomType='xy')
  a$title(text='Data chart')
  a$series(data = list(x = taula$levelArea, y = taula$levelSeveridad, z = taula$Freq, name = "ourdata"))
  a
```

I don't know how to express "data=..." I tried different ways but I can't do it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this can be done using the *hplot* function from the rCharts package.

```
library(rCharts)
taula=data.frame(Freq=c(1,2,3,2,3,4),levelArea=c(1,2,3,4,8,9),levelSeveridad=c(1,1,1,1,1,1))
a <- hPlot(levelSeveridad ~ levelArea, data =taula, type = "bubble", title = "Data chart", size = "Freq" )
a$chart(zoomType = "xy")
a
```

Answer (score 1):

instead of a$series line try the following

```
a$data(taula)
```

it worked for me. although I'm not sure about the desired end result

Comment: if I do a$data(taula) the graph will show a bubble for each value of each column. What I desire is a bubble with levelArea column in x axis,  levelSeveridad column in y axis and the size of the bubble the Freq column. Thanks!